# storing wp_head in a variable?

Tags: php, footer, wp-head

how to store `WP_head` and footer functions in a variable? Is that possible?

I wanted to be like this.

```
$var = wp_head();
```

How can achieve it?

Comment: Mind if I ask why?

Comment: Sure it can be done, however, storing generated text this size in a variable may not be a good idea for performance. So it's better if you say why you need it for. Perhaps there's a better way to achieve what you want without storing `wp_head()` output in a variable.

Comment: @Fayaz Well, to be honest, wp_head isn’t so big comparing to rest of site... Storing it in a variable shouldn’t cause any (even small) performance problems at all...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I said **may be**. Also, I respectfully disagree on the possible performance issue. It's standard practice to output as soon as possible. When you optimize for close to 1000 concurrent views (even for 100 concurrency), "small" things like this add up 

Comment: @Fayaz Of course it is a standard practice. But you've clearly stated, that "storing generated text this size in a variable may not be a good idea for performance" - and it's not true - size of wp_head is comparable or smaller than content and this, of course, is stored in a variable, so your comment doesn't make much sense... And even worse - it may be good for performance, if OP wants to put this string in transient and not generate it every time...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I agree with you. All I tried to say was: "There **may be** scenario, where storing this in variable may cause performance issues :)". for example: a plugin may put all the CSS/JS of a page in the header for some reason. ... So **perhaps** we could provide a better solution if we knew the original requirement.

Comment: @Fayaz Of course it may - but it has nothing to do with size of that string ;) Saying that, I completely agree with rest of your comment.

Answer (score 3):

This function doesn't take any params, so there is no nice way of doing it.

But of course you can do this PHP way using output buffering ;)

```
ob_start();
wp_head();
$var = ob_get_clean();
```